# при использовании консоли pycharm пишет this view is read only

Tags: windows, pycharm

в общем, я решил изучить библиотеку аиограм. установил в виртуальное окружение - пытаюсь импортировать - она не импортируется, хотя пишет что установлена. Не беда, подумал я, и решил запустить pip install прямо в консоли пайчарма. но вот петля, пайчарм пишет, что в его окно доступно только для чтения. погуглил - проблема не новая. однако, все варианты ее решения пригодны только для линукс. прошу помочь мне решить эту проблему на виндовс. заранее спасибо